# Point of extension - Use case

Tags: analysis, uml, use-case

Suppose I have a use case *buy book*, and the main flow is the following:

```
1- The user types the book code that he wants to buy
2- The system replies that there's enough stock of the requested book
3- The user confirm
```

Very simple.

Now suppose I want to give the option to the user to also do another thing between 2 and 3. How should I say it?  I guess it's an extension to this use case, but I'm not sure where it's the point of extension.

As far as I know, if I choose, say, point of extension in 3, then the user has the opportunity to do 3 or do all the extension but not 3. The same behaviour of alternative flows.

But what I want is different. I want some "2.5" or nothing... do it or do nothing instead; not another thing.

I'm sorry for the vague question.

Comment: Use cases are like flow diagrams, they don't need to end at the same point. Branch it off.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the format recommended in Alistair Cockburn's [Writing Effective Use Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702258):

```
2a-  User wants to do another thing:
2a1- The user does another thing
2a2- The system responds in some way, returns to step 3
```

Step 2a occurs after step 2 and before step 3. If the UC ends at step 2a2 then simply replace 'returns to step 3' with 'Use Case ends' or similar.

hth.

Comment: And where I place the "extension point" in the original use case?. Or how it's specified?

Comment: you don't - that's the point.  The original Use Case doesn't explicitly show where it gets extended.  In the main flow you focus on the main success scenario.  Extensions are added by reference to the id of the step in the main scenario where they extend / change behaviour.

Comment: In Cockburn's model, you append extensions directly to extended use case description, so there are no extend relationships and no extension points.

Comment: @Gabriel: would agree there are no _explicit_ extension points, although they are implicit.  Essentially, every step in the extended UC description is a candidate extension point.  Similarly there's an implicit extension relation for each case where an extending UC extends another.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the difference between the use case model in UML and use case descriptions. Extensions point is a concept from UML used to decouple extended and extending use cases. If you want adhere to this, you have to define the position of branching and returning back yourself, because UML says nothing about use case descriptions. I am personally as well as sfinnie a fan of Alistair Cockburns's approach to use cases, however it does not correspond well with the UML standard. There is yet another way, proposed by Bittner (Use case modeling book), who proposes to split the scenario into subflows with headlines.

Comment: good point.  The UML spec gives the impression that "Extension Locations" must be defined explicitly in the original Use Case.  However 'extension point' is not formally specified.  From the UML 2.3 superstructure spec (p608): "The concept of an “extension location” is intentionally left underspecified". Therefore, one could argue Cockburn's scheme is compliant with the intent of the spec.  Specifically, each step of the Main scenario is a candidate extension point (identified by the step number).  ctd...

Comment: ...ctd.  @artu85: generally I'd say it's not worth getting too hung up on.  Go with something that works for you over something that's fully compliant with the spec.  @Gabriel's point is worth noting nonetheless: if you're in a very formal environment (or completing a homework assignment!) then you need to check that Cockburn's scheme is acceptable and/or document your approach around extension points.  hth.

Comment: @sfinnie: just to add, Bittner's scheme doesn't have step numbers, it uses headlines for subflows instead teh rationale being that extensions are coupled to those headlines (extension points), so the scenario can be changed independently (you can add or delete steps without breaking the extension), however in Cockburn's scheme changing the scheme might change step numbers and therefore break extensions... but as said, I am Cockburn's fan, for many other reasons:)

Comment: haven't come across Bittner's approach before.  Thanks for the pointer, will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is an alternate path. An alternate path references a step in the main or in a different alternate path. I usually make that reference the Start step in the alternate. Then the End step is either a reference to where it returns to or an indication the path stops.